# Drupal - how to modify only one instance of a menu with them_menu_link

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I'm using theme_menu_link to modify a menu, in this case main_menu. Evertything works as expected, however I'm using Menu Block to render another instance of the main menu in the sidebar on internal pages.

The problem is, I only want my modifications to show up in the instance of main_menu that I'm using for the site's main navigation, but not in the instance I'm using in the sidebar.

Details:

Here's my theme_menu_link function

```
/**
 * Returns custom HTML for the main navigation menu.
 * Adds an HTML element to top level parent <li> elements
 * to serve as a drop-down menu toggle.
 *
 * this also sets the HTML wrapper for sub menus, to override the above
 * them_menu_tree function, which is intended for top level menus only.
 *
 * @param $variables
 *   An associative array containing:
 *   - element: Structured array data for a menu link.
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
function mytheme_menu_link__main_menu($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $child_menu = $element['#below'];
  $sub_menu = '';

  // if the current top level item has child menus (sub menus)
  if ($child_menu) {
    // unset the sub menu wrapper set above in mytheme_menu_tree__new_main_menu()
    unset($child_menu['#theme_wrappers']);

    // add opening ul tag for the sub menu wrapper to $sub_menu
    $sub_menu = '<ul class="menu sub-menu">';

    // iterate over each sub menu item
    foreach ($child_menu as $child_menu_item){

      // add sub menu item link HTML to a variable
      $child_menu_output = l($child_menu_item['#title'], $child_menu_item['#href']);

      // check to see if item has a title, sincle $element['#below'] returns things besides menu items
      if($child_menu_item['#title']) {
          // output each sub menu item's link and description, wrapped in a <li> element
          $sub_menu .= '<li>' . $child_menu_output .'</li>';
      } // end if shild menu item has a title

    } // end foreach child menu item

    // add closing ul tag for the sub menu wrapper to $sub_menu
    $sub_menu .= '</ul>';
  }

  // output a dummy link for top level items
  $output = '<a href="#" class="nolink">' . $element['#title'] . '</a>';
  return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . '</li>';

}
```

the above function works just like I want it to work on the site's main navigation. However, I do not want this to apply to the instance of main_menu that I'm using in the sidebar with Menu Block. Is there a way to conditionally use them_menu_link based on the region or block the menu is bing rendered it?

Comment: doesn't Menu attributes work for you? https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_attributes

Comment: I've seen that module, but it doesn't seem to address what I'm trying to do: customize menu markup (not just menu item attributes), but scope those customizations to a single instance of a particular menu. My answer below works, though.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out a fix for this one, but I'm not sure if it's the best way to go about it.

Using krumo($variables) inside the `theme_menu_link` function I was able to see that each menu has an array at `$variables['element']['#theme']`, where the first item is the block that the menu is in. So for the main navigation: `$variables['element']['#theme'][0] === 'menu_link__menu_block__1'`, and for the sidebar navigation: `$variables['element']['#theme'][0] === 'menu_link__menu_block__2'`.

Once I saw that it wasn't hard to create an if/else in  the `mytheme_menu_link__main_menu()` function, where we do the customizations for the main menu (outputting `a href="#"` for top level links, etc), but not for the sidebar menu.

So the new and improved `theme_menu_link` function looks like this:

```
function mytheme_menu_link__main_menu($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $sub_menu = '';
  // Only customize the menu instance if its the main navigation, not sidebar navigation, etc.
  // We need to check which block the menu is in, otherwise all instances of main_menu will get this treatment.
  if($element['#theme'][0] === 'menu_link__menu_block__1'){
    $child_menu = $element['#below'];
    // if the current top level item has child menus (sub menus)
    if ($child_menu) {
      // unset the sub menu wrapper set above in mytheme_menu_tree__new_main_menu()
      unset($child_menu['#theme_wrappers']);

      // add opening ul tag for the sub menu wrapper to $sub_menu
      $sub_menu = '<ul class="menu sub-menu">';

      // iterate over each sub menu item
      foreach ($child_menu as $child_menu_item){

        // add sub menu item link HTML to a variable
        $child_menu_output = l($child_menu_item['#title'], $child_menu_item['#href']);

        // check to see if item has a title, sincle $element['#below'] returns things besides menu items
        if($child_menu_item['#title']) {
            // output each sub menu item's link and description, wrapped in a <li> element
            $sub_menu .= '<li>' . $child_menu_output .'</li>';
        } // end if shild menu item has a title

      } // end foreach child menu item

      // add closing ul tag for the sub menu wrapper to $sub_menu
      $sub_menu .= '</ul>';
    }

    // output a dummy link for top level items
    $output = '<a href="#" class="nolink">' . $element['#title'] . '</a>';
    return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . '</li>';
    }

    // Otherwise if we're not in the main navigation block, output a normal menu
    else {
       if ($element['#below']) {
        // unset the sub-menu wrapper set above in mytheme_menu_tree__main_menu()
        unset($element['#below']['#theme_wrappers']);

        // Add a custom wrapper for sub-menus for CSS sanity and profit
        $sub_menu = '<ul class="menu sub-menu">' . drupal_render($element['#below']) . '</ul>';
      }

      $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
      return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . '</li>';
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also try : `global $_current_region;
  if (isset($_current_region) && $_current_region == 'REGION_NAME') {
    // YOUR CODE
  }`

Comment: Thanks! I like this solution much better as it is not specific to a particular block name, but to a region which is more logical and flexible.